# Angular 7 ng-if="" combined conditions

Tags: angular, multiple-conditions

How do i combine conditions in Angular 7?

This code doesn't seem to work:

```
<div *ngIf="isSituation1 || (isSituation3 &&  isSituation2)" [@slideInOut]   role="alert">
<h1>
  Show this if either condition is true
</h1>
</div>
```

I want to show the content if:
isSituation1 = true
or
isSituation3 AND isSituation2 = true

Comment: That's correct. Why don't you show the variables in the template to check if their values are the expected ones? Write in a random part of the html this: `isSituation1: {{isSituation1}}<br>isSituation2: {{isSituation2}} <br> isSituation3: {{isSituation3}}`

Comment: Works for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gecggc

Comment: Eventually you could have a method in your ts file `shouldHeadingBeDisplayed()` who would return `this.isSituation1 || (this.isSituation2 && this.isSituation3)` just for the clarity.

Comment: What is wrong with this code..?

Comment: @CristianTraìna Excellent idea, it helped me understand that the problem was in my head not in the code. The code was actually correct, but I had implemented it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

The template appears to be correct:

```
<!-- app.component.html -->

<div *ngIf="isSituation1 || (isSituation3 &&  isSituation2)" [@slideInOut]   role="alert">
    <h1>Show this if either condition is true</h1>
</div>
```

The JS should include something like this:

```
// app.component.ts

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    isSituation1: boolean = false;
    isSituation2: boolean = false;
    isSituation3: boolean = false;

    // perhaps some logic to check if one of the situations

    ngOnInit() {
        if (someCondition) {
            isSituation1 = true;
        } else if (anotherCondition) {
            isSituation2 = true;
        } else {
            isSituation3 = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Definitely add some `console.log()` statements to check those values.
Also--if by chance `isSituation1-3` are functions, add the parenthesis to the html template `isSituation1() || (isSituation2 && isSituation3)`.